# How to generate additional view controllers in multi-page UI iOS app (horizontal carousel) on demand in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've made a simple weather app as a side project (I'm not a software engineer) that shows temperatures in Fahrenheit and Celsius at the same time. The user can swipe horizontally between cities:

[image: Franz Fahrenheit demo gif]

I've achieved this by using the multi-page app template that was available in Xcode as a new app template up until Xcode 9. When building the app up until Xcode 10, the problem was that when the user added a city to the array of cities, pages for newly added cities would not render *if* the user was on the last page of the carousel at the time of adding a new city. Even if so, when the user swiped left and then back right, the newly added cities would show up. Now, in Xcode 11, new view controllers for newly added cities never render, unless the user relaunches the app. That's a pretty big issue I'd like to fix.

I need help in figuring out how new view controllers can be rendered on demand into the existing multi-page carousel after `addCity` is called, even if the user is currently on the last page and w/o requiring an app restart.

Below is the full code that drives that multi-page carousel. Apologies some of the hacky stuff in there. For context, I'm a non-technical product manager trying to make some iOS apps as side projects.

```swift
import UIKit
import StoreKit

/*
 A controller object that manages a simple model

 The controller serves as the data source for the page view controller; it therefore implements pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController: and pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:.
 It also implements a custom method, viewControllerAtIndex: which is useful in the implementation of the data source methods, and in the initial configuration of the application.

 There is no need to actually create view controllers for each page in advance -- indeed doing so incurs unnecessary overhead. Given the data model, these methods create, configure, and return a new view controller on demand.
 */


class ModelController: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var rootViewController = RootViewController()
    var cities = [""]
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCount")

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.cities = self.defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()

        if self.cities == [""] || self.cities.count == 0  {
            self.cities = ["Current Location", "San Francisco", "New York"]
        }
    }

    func addCity(name:String) {
        self.cities.append(name)
        self.defaults.set(self.cities, forKey: "SavedStringArray")        
    }


    func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int, storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> DataViewController? {
        // Return the data view controller for the given index.
        if (self.cities.count == 0) || (index >= self.cities.count) {
            return nil
        }

        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let dataViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DataViewController") as! DataViewController

        //get city name
        dataViewController.dataObject = self.cities[index]


        return dataViewController
    }



    func indexOfViewController(_ viewController: DataViewController) -> Int {
        // Return the index of the given data view controller.
        // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.
        return self.cities.firstIndex(of: viewController.dataObject) ?? NSNotFound
    }


    // MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }

        index += 1
        if index == self.cities.count {
            return nil
        }

        if index > 1 && currentCount > 2 {
            print ("request review")
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        }

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    }

}
```